# Java Accept Any SubType As Parameter

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a java method which will work correctly with a parameter of either an Integer or a Long.

Is there a way to use generics to have a method that accepts a parameter of either type?

Something like:

```
public <? extends Number> calculateOutput (<? extends Number> inputNumber) {
    return inputNumber + 1;
}
```

Comment: If the class will extend `Number` interface, you can't execute any direct operation like addition by using the + sign.

Comment: With the limitation of either Integer or Long, your method should not be generic. Overloading is probably what you should be using instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get very close by declaring a `T` to extend `Number`.

```
public <T extends Number> T calculateOutput (T inputNumber) {
```

But this will allow any `Number`, even `Float` or `BigInteger`.

Additionally, you won't be able to use `+` because autounboxing won't work here with a generic parameter.  You'd have to test the cases individually (`Long`, `Integer`), but that would defeat the point of having this method generic in the first place.

Comment: Additionally, making a new `T` to return won't be possible, unless you passed in `Class<T>` and used reflection to look up and call the `String` constructor (which is a terrible idea).

Comment: @PaulBellora You're right.  That's another reason why this is a bad idea.